# Can't start JBoss Development studio

Tags: jboss-eap-7

I have no experience in jBoss and can't make it work. I installed it with the installer version and I open up user.home\EAP-7.0.0\bin\standalone.bat and this is what the console looked like. Command froze so I could not copy the text so I took a screendump. Do anyone have a suggestion of how to make it work?

EDITED
I followed this guide

[4.2. INSTALLING JBOSS DEVELOPER STUDIO AND RED HAT JBOSS EAP](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_developer_studio/10.4/html/installation_guide/installer#devstudio_standalone_eap)

with a installer jar-file and it created a EAP-7.0.0 folder but no folder or icon for the jBoss Developer Studio. What I can't find out is how to start jBoss Developer Studio.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your EAP 7 started just fine. Its a clean start of the server without any exceptions. What do you expect ? If you deploy any applications and make changes to any configuration, you will see the console highlighting those messages as well as you can check the log files.

Answer (score 0):

EAP-7.0.0\bin\standalone.bat is the script used to start JBoss EAP in standalone mode in windows OS and the attached screenshot shows that your server has started without any issues.

JBoss Developer Studio is an IDE similar to the eclipse. Did you follow all steps in the document? I would recommend you to redo installation by following all step of chapter 4.2 in the document mentioned. Once the installation is complete successfully you would be able to see application under programs.